# How to pass different datatypes values in RestTemplate FormData?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I'm trying to pass formdata through RestTemplate with different datatypes.

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new MultiValueMap<String, String>();
map..set("app_id", 12);
map..set("app_name", "Partner");
```

But the api I'm hitting throwing Bad request, I tried from postman same request works fine.

Is there any other way I can pass multidatatype request in restemplate formdata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object` in this case :

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new MultiValueMap<>();
```